# Convergence rate of linear regression without chain rule

Tags: convergence-divergence, regression, linear-regression, gradient-descent, regression-analysis

To minimize an MSE, a common method is to perform a gradient descent on the objective. For example, the derivative is:
$\frac{d}{dw} \sum_{i=1}^n (t_i - w x_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n 2 (t_i - w x_i) x_i$.
My question is what happens if we don't have a product that applied the chain rule. To be specific, we perform a gradient descent with: $\sum_{i=1}^n 2 (t_i - w x_i)$ ($x_i$ is not present here).

I can see that the location of the minimum point did not change. However, I feel like the convergence rate may be different.
Would you recommend some ideas to analyze the convergence rate between one with chain rule and one without chain rule?

Thank you!

Comment: Why wouldn't the location of the minimum point change? To not use the chain rule is to pretend that the derivative of your function is actually the derivative of a different function, with possibly a different minimum point. Afraid I'm not seeing the point!

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thank you for your comment! Assuming there exists $w$ that satisfies the solution, we have $t-Xw = 0$ and $X^T (t - X w) = 0$. The "correct" one gives $w = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T t$. However, the first one gives $t - Xw = 0$, which implicitly have a same minima as the correct gradient.

Comment: Maybe I am having a wrong idea.. :(